# axios not fast enough to load the data

Tags: java, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have been trying to use axios to load data with Vue, but get the Undefined error. I am pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with my code, because it works with another person. I think the problem is the page is rendered before axios had chance to fetch the data.

```
 async editGoods(oldGoods) {
                oldGoods.property1 = await this.$http.loadData("/item/someporperty/" + oldGoods.id);
                oldGoods.property2 = await this.$http.loadData("/item/otherproperties/list?id=" + oldGoods.id);
                this.isEdit = true;
                this.show = true;
                this.oldGoods = oldGoods;
            }
```

below is my axios configuration

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import config from './config'

axios.defaults.baseURL = config.api; 
axios.defaults.timeout = 2000; 

axios.loadData = async function (url) {
   const resp = await axios.get(url);
  return resp.data;
}

 Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

This is the error message that I kept getting:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:1741 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js? 
{"id":"data-v-c02e22a2","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video": 
["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble": 
{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
type=template&index=0!./src/pages/item/GoodsForm.vue (4.js:276), 
<anonymous>:332:47)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.esm.js?efeb:3705)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template- 
compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v- 
c02e22a2","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video": 
["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble": 
{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
type=template&index=0!./src/pages/item/GoodsForm.vue (4.js:276), 
<anonymous>:320:23)
     at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.esm.js?efeb:4544)
     at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:2788)
     at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?efeb:3142)
     at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?efeb:3219)
     at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.esm.js?efeb:2981)
     at Array.eval (vue.esm.js?efeb:1837)
     at MessagePort.flushCallbacks (vue.esm.js?efeb:1758)
```

One can take a look at the complete code [here](https://github.com/Liu-java-666/leyou/blob/master/leyou-manage-web/src/pages/item/Goods.vue) and [here](https://github.com/Liu-java-666/leyou/blob/master/leyou-manage-web/src/pages/item/GoodsForm.vue). GoodsForm.vue is the form being rendered.

have been trying to make it work for days, anyone knows how to deal with this?

Comment: where did you use the 'length' ? in v-for ?

Comment: can you show the code of where you use "show"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display the data just after the axios fetched your data, one way to do it is to put an if condition your component base on the value of your data model. like for this one.

in your data you may declare like new data let's say is_load

```
data() {
   return {
      is_loaded:false
   }
}
```

now in your component you should apply a condition to prevent the component to load while the axios is not finish to fetched. like this

```
<template>
     <div v-if="is_loaded">
         ...
         ...
     </div>
</template>
```

then in your axios you may change the value of is_load to true to load your component since the axios already fetched your data. like this

```
 axios.get('api endpoint', {})
      .then(({data}) => {
       ...
       ...
      this.is_loaded = true
 );
```

**note:** you have to set it true when you already finished initializing your data model by your response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, and will try it. I have several length defined in the form(have attached the link for the complete code), cannot tell which one it is referring to. I am not really sure what is the problem here.

Comment: The error still exists, but the page is rendered which means is_loaded is changed to True after the data is loaded into GoodsForm. That means this is probably not caused by the fact that axios is too slow to load data. But I still could not figure out what is really wrong with the code.